# Lazy loaded modules for Jasmine tests. Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, webpack, jasmine, karma-jasmine, lazy-loading

I have some modules in my app to be lazy loaded.
But they can't be used for jasmine tests. I cannot init/load module inside beforeEach or anywhere else.
The problem is I can't find any information regarding this question. Is it possible to do it for my case.

my karma config:

```
config.set({

   plugins: [

       require('karma-babel-preprocessor'),

       require('karma-chrome-launcher'),

       require('karma-jasmine'),

       require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),

       require('karma-safari-launcher'),

       require('karma-spec-reporter'),

   ],

   preprocessors: {

       'app/**/*.spec.js': ['babel'],

       'app/components/my.lazy.module.js': ['babel']

   },

   babelPreprocessor: {

       options: {

           presets: ['es2015'],

           plugins: ['syntax-dynamic-import']

       }

   },

   files: [

       'app/dest/app.js',

       'app/dest/*.bundle.js',

       'app/components/my.lazy.module.js',

       'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',

       'node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js',

       'app/**/*.spec.js'

   ],


    frameworks: [

       'jasmine'

   ],


    reporters: [

       'spec'

   ],
```

I tried loading it in this way:

```
beforeEach(inject(($ocLazyLoad) => {

   import(/* webpackChunkName: "my.lazy" */ 'base/app/components/my.lazy.module.js')

       .then(mod => {

           return $ocLazyLoad.inject(mod.MyLazyModule);

       })

 }));
```

Can it be done in angularjs with webpack? What am I doing wrong? Please, help me)

Comment: Maybe, I should build еach dynamic module separately with webpack?
I have got an error after last changes with dynamic imports inside jasmine tests: 

 "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined"

Comment: I realized that I must put tests and scripts in one common bundle for coreect working lazy loading and dynamic imports.

Comment: I created some demo setup. Take a look https://github.com/ArtemEkzarho/setup_angular_lazyload_karma